# remove the title attribute from links

Tags: links, title

I'm looking for a way to remove the title attribute from links. There is a [old plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-title-tooltips/) but it breaks the site.

The title I would like to remove is in the sidebar widget. Thats the code of the widget part:

```
    // Coupon Catetories Widget
class CLPR_Widget_Coupon_Categories extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'description' => __( 'Display the coupon categories.', APP_TD ), 'classname' => 'widget-coupon-cats' );
        parent::__construct( 'coupon-cats', __( 'Clipper Coupon Categories', APP_TD ), $widget_ops );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        global $wpdb;
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? __( 'Coupon Categories', APP_TD ) : $instance['title']);

        if (strpos($before_widget, 'customclass') !== false)
            $before_widget = str_replace('customclass', 'cut', $before_widget);
        else
            $before_widget = str_replace('customclass', '', $before_widget);

        echo $before_widget;

        if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

            $tax_name = APP_TAX_CAT;
            echo '<div class="coupon-cats-widget"><ul class="list">';

            wp_list_categories("orderby=name&order=asc&hierarchical=1&show_count=0&pad_counts=0&app_pad_counts=1&hide_empty=0&depth=1&number=&title_li=&taxonomy=$tax_name");

            echo '</ul></div>'; 

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        return $new_instance;
    }

    function form($instance) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
        $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
        ?>
            <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', APP_TD ); ?> <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></label></p>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you ellaborate a little as to why you are trying to do this? What problem does it solve?

Comment: I can not change certain description from taxonomy categories and the `title=`shows irritating content. Therefore I need to remove it. Also for SEO Reason.

Comment: Whoever told you it affected SEO was talking BS. Would it not have been better to ask how to change those descriptions? Pretty much everything can be changed, even if it isn't clear how. Additionally, by understanding where the `title` attributes and links are, you might get a better answer. Right now the assumption is that you want them removed from links inside post content, or, the super old links table functionality

Comment: They are located in a custom category list in one of the sidebar widgets.

Comment: How is the custom category list widget implemented?

Comment: "Clipper from appthemes, its old version and the support stopped", that's critical information that is needed to answer the question, you should include it wherever you ask this, but, an unsupported 3rd party plugin is still a 3rd party plugin. 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here and not in scope.

Comment: well its not about the theme is about the title function in general

Comment: How the title is added is an intrinsic part of the widget, knowledge of how the widget is put together as well as its code is necessary, eitherway it's a 3rd party plugin/theme, those are off topic and out of scope. If you disagree you can raise a question on the meta stack and argue your case, comments are not the place

Answer (score 1):

You could provide some more details, like what title attributes you are trying to remove.  In the navigation, content, etc.  Anyway, you could try adding this to your theme or child theme's functions.php file, I have yet to test it though.

```
function remove_title_attributes($input) {
    return preg_replace('/\s*title\s*=\s*(["\']).*?\1/', '', $input);
}
add_filter('wp_list_pages', 'remove_title_attributes');
```

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. Unfortunately it's not working. Still showing title on custom categories list in widgets.

Comment: "custom categories list in widgets" OK, that makes sense, what theme are you using?